# Error connecting to Jupyter notebook localhost

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've tried looking this up, found something similar but not quite. I'm new so if I've posted something commonly posted, my apologies!

When I run jupiter notebook on terminal, this shows up:

Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/myname/Jupyter

0 active kernels

The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=9da2454c0873c8989e93c42f9cc0ee5892da4da6e02fd9b5

Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.

```
Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=9da2454c0873c8989e93c42f9cc0ee5892da4da6e02fd9b5
```

And then when I paste the link to google chrome it says

Safari can't open the page "http://localhost:8888/?token=9da2454c0873c8989e93c42f9cc0ee5892da4da6e02fd9b5" because Safari can't connect to the server "localhost."

I've looked at some other similar issues but I can't find a definite solution other than that port 8888 is being used? Any advice appreciated!

Notes: I've tried this on a Mac running OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. What I did was following.
Step 1: Go to Windows start menu and search for Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3)
Step 2: Type "jupyter notebook" and click "Enter" btn
Step 3: Instead of using localhost use port 127.0.0.1.

Note: Port may be different for you, so just check before you try. [image]